# Jupyter notebook inside WSL

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When running jupyter notebook inside a conda virtual enviornment in wsl (Windows subsystem for linux), copy pasting the url wont work. It always shows "It took too long to respond" or "Connection timed out".

Comment: please reframe your question, as currently it doesn't seem like one, include what you did and add some more details so that others will be able to help you out easily.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem but I wasn't using a virtual environment. Are you trying to connect to the server from the host computer? And are you using the private IP address or localhost address to connect?

I couldn't connect to the server on WSL from the local or remote network.

Apparently, WSL 2 uses a virtual network adapter that has its own IP address. It also changes the IP address every time the server is restarted. I had to write a script that forwarded the network traffic from the virtual machine to the host computer. This allowed me to access the server using the private IP address of the host computer.

I wrote an article about how to do it to make it easier for everyone:

[How to Set Up the Jupyter Notebook Home and Public Server On Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2)](https://medium.com/@thealtruist/how-to-set-up-the-jupyter-notebook-home-and-public-server-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2-wsl2-e6990e328f36)

Answer (score -1):

• Try in another browser (e.g. if you normally use Firefox, try with Chrome). This helps pin down where the
problem is.

• Try disabling any browser extensions and/or any Jupyter extensions you have installed.

• Some internet security software can interfere with Jupyter. If you have security software, try turning it off
temporarily, and look in the settings for a more long-term solution.

• In the address bar, try changing between localhost and 127.0.0.1. They should be the same, but in some
cases it makes a difference.